# Tools to help figure performance improvement with http 2.0 over http 1

Tags: http, http2

Are they any tools to help me figure out performance improvement I will be get with HTTP 2.0 versus HTTP 1
Or any other guidance on how I would go about doing paper calculation.

Typically I have noticed that the tools would eliminate SSL connect time because of socket reuse.

I have looked at one tool - http://http2.loadimpact.com/entry/

Answer (score 1):

I recently found http://www.webpagetest.org/.

You can choose the browser that runs the test, and if you choose a browser that does not support HTTP/2 such as IE10 and one that does such as Chrome, you will get a comparison between HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2.

Comment: Thank you, very useful tool to analyze other aspects of browser behavior. I like the location testing